# GUI doesn't have escalated permissions, Ubuntu 14.04 lightdm

Tags: mount, permissions, lightdm, ldap

Relatively new user here.

So I am having some permission issues with the desktop. The sysadmin before me set up Ubuntu 12.04 on the other machines, and it seems to work OK. I set a new machine up with 12.04 attempting to use the same configuration but I decided to try 14.04 because 12.04 was acting kind of strange (freezing, crashing problems with graphics).

So far so good, but the UI does not give the user ability to mount USB, unlock User Account settings etc. He is part of sudoers, and from terminal can mount USB, and do everything else fine, but the graphic desktop does not allow this. He authenticates through an LDAP, but I'm not sure if this  is this issue, because I authenticate on the same LDAP with my machine and my GUI has the ability to unlock user accounts and mount USB.

Answer (score 0):

In `sudo pam-auth-update` I made sure the GNOME Keyring Daemon was also selected. This fixed the issue.